# How to access object properties in event bound method

Tags: javascript, class, this

I need to access object properties from within a method that has an event object (window). The this-keyword refers to the window object, not to the actual instantiated object. Trying to implement an arrow function produces errors. The code ist a minimal snippet. So I basically need to know how to refer to the a-property (this-keyword in the loop).

```
<script>
    class A{
        constructor({a, b, c}){
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        evaluate (event){
            let old = event.oldUrl;
            if ( A.isComplex() ) {
                for (let i = 0; i < this.a.length; i++){
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }

        static isComplex(){
            //do something
            return true;
        }
    }

    let obj = new A({a:['a', 'b', 'c'], b:'y', c:'z'});
    window.onhashchange = obj.evaluate;
</script>
```

Comment: You can set what the `this` keyword references with `bind()`: `window.onhashchange = obj.evaluate.bind(obj)`

Comment: Try this: `evaluate (event, obj)` and call the method as `obj.evaluate(this)`

Comment: A common pattern in React is inside your constructor do -> `this.evaluate = this.evaluate.bind(this)`  , ps:  you of course can use this technique outside of React..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.